# Unexpected behavior with custom .htaccess rewrite rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I have been working on some rewrite rules which aren't working as expected. These are some sample requests I am trying to rewrite:

```
/             -> /index.php?page=Home
/Home         -> /index.php?page=Home
/Teaching/Foo -> /index.php?page=Teaching&id=Foo
/Teaching/Bar -> /index.php?page=Teaching&id=Bar
/Download/ue8 -> /index.php?action=Download&id=ue8
/Download/24a -> /index.php?action=Download&id=24a
(default)     -> /index.php?page=Home
** OR ALTERNATIVELY **
(default)     -> /index.php?page=FileNotFound
(and maybe rewrite the visible URL to /FileNotFound)
```

I mainly want to hide as much of the urls as possible and prevent both directory listing and direct access to my files located in specific folders and only allow access to downloadable files via `/Download/FileId` while having my usual pages for different lectures accesible via `/Teaching/SomeLecture`.

So far I have been using this snippet for the `/Home` and `/Teaching` stuff:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Teaching/([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ index.php?page=Teaching&id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^Home$ index.php?page=Home [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,R=301]
```

I am not completely sure about all of these directives and I noticed, that there are currently some flaws to it.

1. Trying to access a non-existant file, e.g. `/Files/Bad/Path.pdf`, forwards the user to `/?page=Home` which should be redirected either to `/`, `/Home` or display the contents of `/index.php?page=FileNotFound` without changing the URL at all or redirecting to `/FileNotFound` depending on the rule of `(default)`. I am not really sure which solution might be the most suitable in this scenario.
2. Trying to access some folders which do exist results in an infinite redirection loop while folders which do not exist apparently redirect to `/`. In both cases it feels right to redirect to `/FileNotFound` I suppose?

Could you please work out a set of rules that might suit my needs in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many redundant directives in your .htaccess. Replace all of your .htaccess with this:

```
# Turn off mod_spelling
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
   CheckSpelling off
   CheckCaseOnly off
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# block direct access to file and directories in these directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(Templates|Files) - [NC,F]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(Download|Teaching)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(Home)?/?$ index.php?page=Home [L,NC,QSA]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: There is a small error in the second to last line where you have `QSA.NC` instead of `QSA,NC`. Furthermore I encountered some interesting behavior of the server. If I try to access a file it tries to correct mistyped urls and in some cases it can't decide and shows me [this](http://i.imgur.com/cpTq8lX.png). Do you happen to know how to completely deny direct access to files other than `index.php` in addition to my rules so far? Other than this small issue it seems to be what I was looking for after all.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment: when I try to access `/Files/Ana14/` directly it forwards to `/Files/Ana15/` because it's the only existing folder that has a similiar pattern and then it shows a 403 error message. In my second case there are multiple possibilties during the 300 status code but I do not want to show this. In both cases I would like to display appropriate error pages.

Comment: Disabling `mod_spelling` does indeed fix the multiple choices! I guess that I am supposed to create new `.htaccess` files in the other directories with `Deny from all` to disable direct access to those files?

Comment: My `index.php` includes specific image files and some behind-the-scenes php files and some pdf files if the user requests a download. I would like to prevent accessing the folders `/Files`, `/Templates`, etc as well as their sub-folders and actual files like pdfs. That's why I thought an `.htaccess` with a `Deny from all` specifically for each directory would be better.

Comment: This version seems to fulfull all I need - thank you very much.