# Unexpected request handling with substrings of existing folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Let `http://test.server/` be my current web server for testing purposes then I have a folder in there called `Homepage` which holds the code for the homepage (duh.). In the `Homepage` folder there are a some folders (like `Templates`) which have `.htaccess` files with `deny from all`. In `Homepage` I do have a quite long `.htaccess` as well with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
    CheckSpelling off
    CheckCaseOnly off
</IfModule>

Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Homepage
ErrorDocument 403 /Homepage/403
ErrorDocument 404 /Homepage/404

# Block direct access to files and directories in these directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(Forbidden) - [NC,F]

# Deny access to configuration files
<Files  ~ "\.ini">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)?/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

So when i try to access `http://test.server/Homepage/Templates/` this invokes a 403 error and the specified `ErrorDocument` described by `/Homepage/403` is properly shown (and parsed by my backend) while still being on `http://test.server/Homepage/Templates/`.

**However**, when I try to access a Url that is a substring of the protected folder like `http://test.server/Homepage/Template/`, `http://test.server/Homepage/Temp/` etc. the server **redirects** (!) to `http://test.server/Template/` or `http://test.server/Temp/` and shows a generic 404 document that was not setup since I have no `.htaccess` in the root folder. I was expecting the `ErrorDocument` for 404 to be shown like 403 does correctly while still being at `http://test.server/Homepage/Temp/` for example. This means this isn't even sent to my handler in my `index.php` but directly handled by Apache which seems to be trying to find some fallback rules in the root folder.

What's the mistake I made in my `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is due to this `# Redirect Trailing Slashes` rule.

You can replace that rule with:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: It seems to be working now as intended, thank you very much - what is funny is that it was actually you who wrote me this back then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33220616/796036

Comment: Actually I checked that answer also. That answer was for the case when .htaccess is in root but here you have it in `/Homepage/`. Anyway this new rule I've suggested will work from both .htaccess