# POST variables getting lost using mod_rewrite rules (incorrect)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Edit:** The error turned out to be something as trivial as forgetting to set the `name` attribute. It has nothing to do with my `.htaccess`.

---

[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) helped me already [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33219783/796036) and [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40981627/796036) occasion. Once again I am struggling with mod_rewrite and I wanted to simplify it and handle requests in my php code so that I never have to bother with mod_rewrite again since it drives me nuts. Therefore I have simplified my current iteration of the `.htaccess` file which looks like this:

```
# RewriteBase and ErrorDcoument have a conflict
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Homepage
ErrorDocument 403 /Homepage/HttpUnauthorized
ErrorDocument 404 /Homepage/HttpNotFound

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

# Removes index.php from URLs (actually everywhere, even mid url!)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In my backend (called by `index.php`) I am parsing the requests like this:

```
$queryArguments = explode('/', array_shift($_REQUEST));
// First element is null anyways.
array_shift($queryArguments);
$controllerCustomUrl = array_shift($queryArguments);
```

Something like `http://sandbox.com/Homepage/FooList/Argument1/Argument2` would yield `$controllerCustomUrl = 'FooList'` and `$queryArguments = ['Argument1', 'Argument2']`. This works decent and as expected thus far, however I am struggling with submitting forms right now.

When I submit my form available at `http://sandbox.com/Homepage/Test` the url in the browser gets changed to `http://sandbox.com/Homepage/Test?` with the question mark at the end, which is pretty strange to say the least. Furthermore the `$_POST` variable is empty and I am losing my submitted data on the way.

I am pretty sure that this unexpected behaviour occurs due to some wrong directives in my `.htaccess`, presumably wrong or too many redirections etc. but I can't seem to find the source of the bug. Do you see what is wrong?

*Further information on the rules:* As before, I want to remove trailing slashes at the end of all urls, direct (visible) access to index.php as well and have url patterns like this `/:controller/:arg1/:arg2/.../:argN` where the string indicated by `:controller` is used to find the corresponding page class file while supplying it with the arguments `:arg1` to `:argN`.

---

As requested my form tag:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Comment: Show us what your starting form tag looks like.

Comment: @CBroe Please refer to my edit.

Comment: And what is the URL in the address bar when that form is shown?

Comment: @CBroe The form is visible with `http://sandbox.com/Homepage/Test` being in the address bar. After submitting it, the address bar displays `http://sandbox.com/Homepage/Test?`. I do presume that the redirects with `R=301` are breaking this.

Comment: Can you show what the browser dev tools network panel shows after you submitted the form? (Might want to press the "record" button or whatever the equivalent of that is in your browser, so that redirects don't wipe the log.)

Comment: @CBroe The tool shows indeed that the page is delivered using GET even though I have been submitting a POST form: http://i.imgur.com/HPmfc8T.png

Comment: Can you show an actual live example maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now according to your updated example [URL removed], your form contains the following elements:

> ```
> <input type="text" class="form-control " id="inputField" placeholder="This form will 
>   succeed if you enter 'secret'">
> ```

and

> ```
> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">...
> ```

Neither of those have a `name` attribute, so they are both skipped by step 3.1 in the [form data set construction algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set), and you effectively send an empty POST request without any parameters.

---

EDIT: Previous explanation removed, example shown contained a different HTML error at the time.

Comment: That is an error that happened when copy&pasting a few days ago - thanks for pointing that out, however it still does not work. Internally I put a breakpoint that will exit and output debug messages once POST data is available but the form it still not propagating the POST data through my rules. - I will look through my backend code once again to make sure I didn't forgot something since my inspector is telling me now that the page is indeed having POST type but my code says it has no data.

Comment: I have been going through the code and `$_POST` is always empty - so it seems plausible the data gets lost somewhere.

Comment: Well that's what you get, when you're coding so late. I completely mistook the `id` and `name` attributes and it works as expected. Thank you very much - you can edit your answer accordingly to remove unrelated suggestions and the link to my test page. Thanks again for your insight!